# Retrieving data from Realtime Database only once

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want my app to allow the user to back up his data on Realtime Database and restore it. I've already implemented the backup function but I got stuck when I tried to implement the restore function. Because a `ChildEventListener` only gives you the ability to retrieve data live, which is a problem because I need to know when the backup finished downloading. How can I retrieve data only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the data only once, you need to use the following:

> [`public void addListenerForSingleValueEvent (ValueEventListener listener)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener))
>
> Add a listener for a single change in the data at this location. This listener will be triggered once with the value of the data at the location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use addListenerForSingleValueEvent() instead
For Example :

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("Your Node")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    // Do whatever you need with your data (retrieved only once)
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle Database Error
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

For a database reference object, the same way one can add an event listener, it can also be removed, using `removeEventListener`.

Instead of creating an anonymous object like this

```
checkBuy.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                checkPurchase(snapshot);

                addListView();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
});
```

you can create a named object of `ValueEventListener` and remove it from the database reference object using `removeEventListener`, at the end of the `onDataChange` method

```
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                checkPurchase(snapshot);

                addListView();

                checkBuy.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
});

checkBuy.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

The code inside `onDataChange` method gets executed only once as the `ValueEventListener` object is removed as soon as the last line of the method gets executed.